# Covering map of $\mathbb R \mathbb P^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

The question I am trying to answer is:
Does the quotient map $ q:[0,1] \times [0,1] \to \mathbb R \mathbb P^2$ extend to a covering map $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R \mathbb P^2$

I know that the quotient map $ [0,1] \times [0,1] \to T$ extends to a covering map $\mathbb R^2 \to T $ but I'm not even sure how to approach the new question (as I thought it would be similar).

For a start I don't know how to extend $q$ onto $\mathbb R^2$ because the way I'm thinking about it is by identifying opposite edges of a square, whereas for the Torus I'm using exp to define my covering map.

I also know that the quotient map $p: S^2 \to \mathbb R \mathbb P ^2$ is a covering map but not sure how this would help when looking at the quotient map above.

Any help/hints would be great, thank you.

Comment: The universal cover of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is the 2-sphere $S^2$.

Comment: Well we can identify $\mathbb{R}P^2$ with the space of all line through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$. In other words its the set of all points in 3-space such that $(x,y,z)~(tx,ty,tz)$ where $t\in\mathbb{R}/0$ We can see that each line can be identified with two points of the sphere $S^2$ and under the identification of antipodal points we get the projective plane. I don't believe that this extends to a covering map.

Comment: Thank you, I was missing a result about universal coverings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no cover from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}P^2$ because the universal cover of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is $S^2$ which is unique up to homeomorphism.

For the particular case you are thinking about, extending the quotient map from the square to a covering map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}P^2$ by "fitting" a infinitely many squares into the plane, note that this is would be an infinite sheeted cover and hence not possible for algebraic reasons.

If such an infinite sheeted cover $p:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}P^2$ existed then $p_*(\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^2)) = \{0\} \subset \pi_1(\mathbb{R} P^2) = \mathbb{Z}_2$ would be of infinite index.  But of course $\mathbb{Z}_2$ has order $2$ so this is impossible.

Comment: Thank you I was struggling to understand myself how to extend the map onto $\mathbb R^2$ but what you said makes sense. Why though would $\{0\}$ have infinite index in $\mathbb Z_2$?

Comment: The index of $p_*$ is the number of sheets of the cover.

Comment: That is great thank you I should have been thinking about it more generally. I didn't actually realise universal covers where unique up to homeomorphism although I've now shown that from a lemma I knew. 

I'm also not aware that the index of $p_\star$ is the number of sheets of the cover. Is it something easy to see? Don't worry if not as I now understand the other argument.

Comment: It isn't difficult to prove.  I'm sure it's in any text on algebraic topology, in particular in Hatcher (available free on line) on page 61.